# Mail sent with Thread but still Hangs application in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, email

I have developed an application which sends Email. Initially the application was getting hanged during sending mail therefore I thought of sending mail through `Thread` but even sending mail with Thread my application still gets hang when the email is being sent.

***UPDATE***

I have updated my code but still same problem now when join() is used.

Here is my code *(I have shorten code for ease of understanding my thread implementation)*

```
boolean wasMailSent = false;
public void sendMyMail()
{
    Thread sendEmail = new Thread(new sendMail("abc@xyz.com"));
    sendEmail.start();
    Thread confirmIt = new Thread(new confirmMailSent());
    sendEmail.start();
    try
    {  
        sendEmail.join();  
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
    confirmIt.start();
}

public class sendMail implements Runnable
{
    String sendTo;
    public sendMail(String sendTo)
    {
        this.sentTo = sendTo;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        //Code to send mail
        wasMailSent=true;
    }
}

public class confirmMailSent implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
        if(wasMailSent)
        {
            feedbackText.setText(null);
            feedbackName.setText(null);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Mail was sent successfully.", "Mail Sending", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to add the code in the sendMail method...

Comment: And by the way, where is sendEmail in your code? I only see sendMail..

Comment: (You didn't actually need to add the code; your comment was sufficient.)

Comment: I see a problem in your updated code. Your are using Swing components. I recomend in this case the use of a SwingWorker

Comment: You could use one of the [executor services](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) as well and avoid the overhead of creating new threads each time (e.g. a thread pool or single thread executor will do the job; and in the same or less lines of code as what you have now - very easy to implement).

Comment: @JasonC I didn't even know about Executor Services. Will read about that. Thanks may be you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code to send mail must be in run()

```
public void sendMyMail()
{
    Thread sendEmail = new Thread(new SendMail("abc@xyz.com"));
    sendEmail.start();
}

public class SendMail implements Runnable
{
    String sendTo;

    public SendMail(String sendTo)
    {
       this.sendTo = sendTo;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
    //Code to send Email
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Also recommend adding `@Override` to `run()` for clarity and sanity checking.

Comment: Nop. It still gets hanged

Comment: are you getting some Exceptions? JOptionpane included may cause it. As I said you in a comment to your question. You should use a Swingworker if you want to update the interface in your thread, or extract messageboxes from the mail sending, I'll choose the second one. Better than catching Exceptions, throw them to the Thread invoker.

Comment: Ezequiel sorry may be that annoyed you but please see my updated code I have used join() of threads. Sorry for my last code, I thought join() had nothing to do with application hang.

Comment: If I remove my **join()** method and second thread. it works great.

Comment: Thread#join() means: pause actual thread until this thread is done. So if you use `sendEmail.join();` in a thread, this thread will wait until sendMail completion. and you got blocked

Comment: No mail is sent successfully if I do not use join() and other thread.

Comment: Okay that's nice catch. So what can I do to check if the mail is sent and show a message to user?

Comment: You need to check if fisrt thread is done. Check FutureTask class, a especialized Runnable. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html or SwingWorker and its methods doInBackGround() to execute logic in a thread, and its done() method, to show the JOptionPane

Comment: Thanks alot. Very very nice of you thanks a lot. That solved my problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Check as valid answer then, please.

Comment: Though Jason had also helped me great and suggested same thing as you and taught 2 new things but your code helped me to easily understand the problem therefore my accepted answer should be yours.

Answer (score 3):

It's because your code to send mail is in the `sendMail` constructor. It's not getting run on your new thread at all. It's getting run immediately on your calling thread when you do `new sendMail()` (after which your thread starts and does nothing, really, since `run()` is empty). You'd want that code to be in `run()`, which is executed on the new thread, rather than in the constructor.

By the way, it is traditional to start class names with upper case letters rather than lower case. It makes them easy to distinguish (and also doesn't confuse SO's syntax highlighter).

Comment: Also, class names commonly are nouns instead of adjectives or verbs. It would sound better if the class was named `AsyncMailSender` or something like that.

Comment: @JavaDrunk Then there are other things going on that you are not telling us about, or there is something you are missing elsewhere, as this *is* the correct way to implement this. You will have to do some work to narrow down what is happening. Adding debugging `System.out.println` statements to trace through execution, or running in a debugger, could give you some good hints. Also print out your exceptions; are you hanging on dialog boxes?

Comment: Jason sorry may be that annoyed you but please see my updated code I have used join() of threads. Sorry for my last code, I thought join() had nothing to do with application hang.

Comment: If I remove my **join()** method and second thread. it works great.

Comment: @JavaDrunk You really should have also showed that first; with the `join()` in there, fixing your `run()` was not enough on its own to solve the issue (both contributed to the problem). Had you read the documentation for [`join()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()) it would have been apparent.

Comment: @JavaDrunk By the way rather than using the `wasMailSent` flag, consider using a `Callable` instead of a `Runnable` and using a `Future` to obtain the result (if you use the executor services I mentioned they make this quite easy).

Comment: I am really sorry for my stupidity to not completely show my join() code but as Ezequiel saying my second thread is hanging application due to join, then what else can I do to let me user show a message when a mail is successfully sent

Comment: Jason thanks alot for your kind support and specially letting me know about executor service, I will definitely check that. Thanks again

Comment: You thought me great and I am really confused who's answer should be accepted because both answers are great and you taught me new things.